# Как отфильтровать одним input по двум свойствам?

Tags: angular, input, angular10

Есть модель PrintingEdition, мне нужно одним input  отфильтровать по title и description , как это можно сделать

```
export interface PrintingEdition{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    currency: CurrencyTypeEnum;
    type: PrintingTypeEnum;
    authorsId: number[];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Набросал код, вроде ничего сложного. Через combineLatest соединяешь два потока из формы и массива, и сравниваешь необходимые значения.
Примерно так
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qxs6va?file=src/app/app.component.ts)